# How to read complete file usind pickle.load()?

Tags: python, pickle, try-except

Suppose, I want to read the complete file using pickle.load(), not just a single line. I know I can use `try - except` but is there any other method to read it?
I am using this:

```py
    import pickle
    d = {}
    for i in range(2):
        roll_no = int(input("Enter roll no: "))
        name = input("Enter name: ")
        d[roll_no] = name

     f = open("test.dat", "ab")
     pickle.dump(d, f)
     f.close()

     f = open("test.dat", "rb")
     while True:
         try:
            print(pickle.load(f))
        except EOFError:
            break
```

Comment: give us your code

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Done

Comment: Did you save the file with `pickle.dump()`?

Comment: use cpickle library

Comment: import cpickle and then cpickle.load(f)

Comment: @keith yes, I have edited the complete code

Comment: It looks like you have pickled objects into the file multiple times. Its not so much that you want to read multiple lines, you want to read multiple pickle serialized records. You many want to clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Python library does not support this within a single instruction. You can define your own helper function though:

```python
import io
import pickle

from typing import List

def unpickle(file: io.IOBase) -> List[object]:
    result = []
    while True:
        try:
            result.append(pickle.load(file))
        except EOFError:
            break
    return result
```

You can then call it like this

```python
with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    objects = unpickle(f)
```

`objects` will contain *all* the objects that have been serialized in `data.pickle` here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file.tell` to see if you are at EOF

```
f = open("test.dat", "rb")
# go to end of file and get position
size = f.seek(0, 2)
# now return to the front and pull pickle records
f.seek(0)    
while f.tell() < size:
    print(pickle.load(f))
```